# How to calculate next/same day based on availability table?

Tags: r, excel, datetime, excel-formula, datetimeoffset

I am working on an excel formula to find next available day based on an excel table. I have two tables, A and B, table A has dates and result column, table B has dates and counts, I would like to get date from table B into the result column of table A based on count of dates from table A and B. 
Please note the date in "result" column of table A is the expected output and it is is always same or higher date than in date column of table A.  Date format is month/date/year

```
table A 
Date    Result
01-02-2018  01-02-2018
01-02-2018  01-02-2018
01-05-2018  01-05-2018
01-05-2018  01-05-2018
01-05-2018  01-07-2018
01-05-2018  01-07-2018
01-06-2018  01-07-2018
01-07-2018  01-10-2018
01-09-2018  01-10-2018
01-11-2018  01-12-2018
01-12-2018  01-12-2018


table B 
Date    Count
01-02-2018  3
01-03-2018  1
01-04-2018  3
01-05-2018  2
01-07-2018  3
01-10-2018  3
01-12-2018  2
```

Comment: Hi, Table A, "result" column is the expected output, it is based on table B 
"Date" and "Count" column. An excel formula would be ideal, I am okay with r function too. :)

Comment: Please explain in more details how to **based on the `Date` and `Count`** to return a date in Table A?

Comment: what i mean is the most a date can appear in table A result column is based on table B's count column. For eg, for rows, 3,4, 5 in table A, their Date is listed as 01-05-2018 but in table B 01-05-2018 has a count of 2, so the rows 3, 4 of result column in table A have 01-05-2018 and row 5 had the next date listed in table B i.e. 01-07-2018. Here, for every date in table A, the result date is either same date or the next higher date

Comment: Are the dates in Table A and Table B always in ascending order or they can come in at random order, and what would you want to show if there is no match? Also what version of Excel are you using (which may open new ways to solve the issue).

Comment: All the dates in both table are in ascending order, there maybe few dates that dont match between table A and B. In this case you can see date 01-06-2018 is present in table A but not B. I am using excel for office 365, 32 bit

Comment: @Terry W, could you elaborate on what you mean by no match?

Comment: You need to explain what you want to happen in cases when there is no match.

Comment: There would always be a date equal  to or greater than in results column of table A, as the table B dates and count would keep going even if dates in table A are not present..

Comment: I have added a few more rows to the tables to demonstrate more clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this task took me longer than expected to tackle and finally I come up with a solution with the help of a couple **helper columns** (not sure if it is an option?).

So suppose your have the following **named ranges**:

- **TblA_Date** being all the dates in your `Table A` (This one is optional as I did not use it in my solution...);
- **TblB_Date** being all the dates in your `Table B`.

Firstly, I *"expanded"* your `Table B` to a list structure laying out all the dates:

[image: Expand Table B]

The formula for the first helper column in Cell `J2` of my example is:

```
=SUM($I$2:I2)
```

> which is to find the running total of the counts in `Table B`.

The formula for the second helper column in Cell `M2` is:

```
=INDEX(TblB_Date,MATCH(1,--(ROW(A1)<=$J$2:$J$8),0))
```

> which is "laying" out all the dates from `Table B` using row position as a reference and comparing it with the running total of counts and returning the corresponding date. Given that it is an **array formula** you **MUST** press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> upon finishing the formula in the formula bar otherwise it will not function correctly. Then you can simply drag the formula down to apply across.
>
> Please note I have given the second helper column `M2:M18` (excluding `M19` which is an error) a name **TblB_Date_Expanded**.

The next step is to find the position of the desired date in **TblB_Date_Expanded** based on your conditions which are

1. *"for every date in table A, the result date is either same date or the next higher date"* **AND**
2. *the date from `Table B` can only be used no more than its corresponding count*.

[image: Index Column]

The formula in cell `E2` is:

```
=MAX(MATCH(AGGREGATE(15,6,TblB_Date_Expanded/(A2<=TblB_Date_Expanded),1),TblB_Date_Expanded,0),E1+1)
```

where `A2` is the first date in `Table A` as you will see in my next screenshot.

> The logic is to use **AGGREGATE** function to return the closest starting date in `TblB_Date_Expanded` base on the given date in `Table A`, then use **MATCH** function to return the row position, and lastly use **MAX** function to increase the position by `1` if the same position has been used already (in the row above).

With known row position, we can easily return the corresponding date from `TblB_Date_Expanded` using the following formula:

```
=INDEX(TblB_Date_Expanded,E2)
```

[image: Result]

> **Thoughts**, the difficult part that I cannot overcome is the use of "circular reference" or "self-reference" in the helper columns. In other words, I am not sure how to use a single formula to return an array of values whose calculation is depending on its precedent value. I hope someone may come up a more elegant way of solving this question :)

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: hi Terry, I know this was a bit tricky problem, glad you got it figured out. This works excellent, and I really appreciate it.

Comment: @user12229564 happy to help. I did not have much time to test the outcome so if you come across any exceptions do let me know and I will have a look as soon as I am available.

Answer (score 0):

Assume "table A" put in A1:A9, include `A1`: "table A", `A2:B2` (header) : "Date" and "Result"

"table B" put in A11:A1, include `A11`: "table B", `A12:B12` (header) : "Date" and "Count"

In "Result" column `B3`, formula copied down :

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$3:A3,A3)<=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,$A$13:$B$17,2,0),0),A3,AGGREGATE(15,6,$A$13:$A$17/($A$13:$A$17>=MAX(A3,INDEX(A3:A$10,MATCH(1,INDEX(0+(A3:A$10<>A3),0),0)))),1))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have tried this formula and it is working partly correct, but for the example listed in the question is it not working, would like to add the date format is month/date/year.

Comment: I put "table A" in A1:A13, included A1: "table A", A2:B2 (header) : "Date" and "Result" ,  "table B" put in A16:A24, include A16: "table B", A17:B17 (header) : "Date" and "Count" , result formula in B3    =IF(COUNTIF(A$3:A3,A3)<=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,$A$18:$B$24,2,0),0),A3,AGGREGATE(15,6,$A$18:$A$24/($A$18:$A$24>=MAX(A3,INDEX(A3:A$13,MATCH(1,INDEX(0+(A3:A$13<>A3),0),0)))),1))

Comment: Based on your posted example, please clarify which formula cell result don't matched with your expected. And for your notice that, my formula used a AGGREGATE function of which available since Excel 2010, the lower Excel version wouldn't work.

Comment: For row 8 01-07-2018, i am supposed to get answer of 01-10-2018 but i got 01-07-2018, making this date appear 4 times though count in table B is set for 3 for date 01-07-2018.

Comment: Don't shift your goal post without notice, this is your 3rd time in changing your post original data. Sorry, unable to give you any help.

Comment: I meant to make the question more clear, didnt mean to shift the focus as i am trying to scale the logic to a large dataset. I'd appreciate any further help.

Comment: It a forum general rule, don't changed your original post data. You have right to make the question clearer by submit a 2nd post new data and stated what is the changing in compare to the 1st post data. Once you break the rule no one willing give you any help.

Comment: I understand that, but this was my first post and am still trying to figure out :/

Comment: I think sometimes it is necessary for the OP to update its post to clarify the question which could potentially save a lot of time for others who want to solve the question. What @user12229564 should do is to clearly state which part is newly added to the original post by starting a new paragraph with **EDIT#2** or **EDIT#3** etc.